# C# controlling the number of simultaneous threads running

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to implement a program which allow a maximum of ten people to simultaneously pick an object say a cup or car. Meaning that when one of then is finished there is a free place for another person to pick an object. The maximum time one could spend picking is 5 seconds. I have tried to use an array of tasks but this is not working since the picker are on different machines. I could update the database anytime one person picks an object and then check the value from the database but I think, it is a bad Idea. How could I control those threads or picks?

I need to control/keep track the maximum number of threads run irrespective of where the pick of the object is done.

Thank you

Comment: What about using a thread pool?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't sound like a threading question, but more of a server/client object manager. There are lots of directions you could go with this, but a simple solution would be to have a service that manages each object.

```
/* Common interface each object shares */
public interface IObject { ... }
/* Sharable Object implementing IObject */
public class Cup : IObject { ... }

/* This class would be exposed via WCF or Remoting */
public class ObjectSharer : IObjectSharer {
    enum ObjectType { Cup, Car }
    IObject GetObject(ObjectType ObjType) { ... }
    ReturnObj(IObject) { ... }
}
```

You'll have to fill in the implementation, but hopefully this gives you some ideas on how you could approach this type of problem.

In the GetObject method, jwde's suggestion of using a Semaphore would be a good way to handle resource management, limiting the object(s) to 10.

Answer (score 3):

A [Semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx)  is the idiomatic data structure for limiting the number of concurrent accesses to a resource.

Example:

```
public static class foo
{
    private static Semaphore _resources = new Semaphore(_limit, _limit);
    private const _limit = 10;
    public void Pick()
    {
        _resources.WaitOne();
        doWork();
        _resources.Release();
    }
}
```

Now only 10 threads can `doWork()` at once. Once one finishes, the next one will get to start.

Answer (score -2):

It is very hard to understand what is being asked..

But I think you want to control your threads?

In that case, you can suspend a thread, which can be used to synchronizing threads. However this can leak to deadlocks.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  I just edit edited the question and added some information. I need to control/keep track of the maximum number of threads run irrespective of where the pick of the object is done.